# useRef's reference value change on re-render caused by strict mode while useState does not

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state, use-ref

I was trying to run something in useEffect, but did not wanted it to run on initial render so I created a hook useIsMounted.

```
  import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

export const useIsMounted = () => {
    const isMountedRef = useRef(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(isMountedRef.current);//prints false on first render and true on second render.
        isMountedRef.current = true;
    }, []);
console.log(isMountedRef.current);//prints false on both renders
    return isMountedRef.current;
};
```

Here I have put two console logs  and I am getting different values on two renders(one caused by strict mode) while the one outside useEffect returns same value on both renders.

Also whenever I use useState instead  of useRef it console log's same value (false) on both render  outside and inside of the useEffect.

here is the sample

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const useIsMounted = () => {
    const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(isMounted); //prints false on both renders
        setIsMounted(true);
    }, []);
    console.log(isMounted);//prints false on both renders
    return isMounted;
};
```

Comment: With Strict Mode starting in React 18, whenever a component mounts in development, React will simulate immediately unmounting and remounting the component:

* React mounts the component.
    * Layout effects are created.
    * Effect effects are created.
* React simulates effects being destroyed on a mounted component.
    * Layout effects are destroyed.
    * Effects are destroyed.
* React simulates effects being re-created on a mounted component.
    * Layout effects are created
    * Effect setup code runs
On the second mount, React will restore the state from the first mount.

Comment: With these reasons it is clear that while re-mounting , the state is restored from the first mount. [strict-mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) _italic_ and since I wasn't using the function version for setState I was accessing the stale value of isMounted. So I was getting false on both renders